# setTimeOut + window.onblur+ window.onfocus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m trying to use setTimeout to recall a function. When window is not on focus so we will set that function to take a pause until window is on focus again. Let see my script

```
(function() {
    var time = 10000,
        delta = 100,
        tid;

    tid = setInterval(function() {
        if ( window.blurred ) { return; }    
        time -= delta;
        if ( time <= 0 ) {
            clearInterval(tid);
            dosomething (user_id); // function to do something
        }
    }, delta);
})();

window.onblur = function() { window.blurred = true; };
window.onfocus = function() { window.blurred = false; };
```

Actually it work as I expected BUT

**My question is :**

- I'm trying to change the method to-----> setTimeout and clearTimeout Why it doesn't work ?
- After many test I found that this function doesn't work in IE, do we have any solution ?

Comment: use jquery, not js for this kind of thing. in jquery this is very very simple, and there are multiple methods, depends on exact situation.

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, I have tried, But maybe I did it in the incorrect way, so it doesn´t work. Could you please point me how to do ? (I´m not so used to jQuery in this method.)

Comment: `.delay()` may be what you need, or if a animation then `(500, function(){code here})`, google jquery timing or something like that, you can easily use a "animation" as a timeout, although with jquery you probably will never have to.